# How can I run a function in a structure that implements an interface?

Tags: go, interface

Hi guys i have this code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main(){
    var structObj *Struct
    Obj1 := Obj1{}
    Obj2 := Obj2{}
    structObj = New(&Obj1)
    fmt.Println(structObj.name)
    structObj = New(&Obj2)
    fmt.Println(structObj.runFunc)
}

type IStruct interface {
    Id() string
    Name() string
    Run() string
}

type Obj2 struct {
}

func (self *Obj2) Id() string {
    return "Obj2Id"
}

func (self *Obj2) Name() string {
    return "Obj2"
}

func (self *Obj2) Run() string {
    return "Obj2 run func"
}

type Obj1 struct {
}

func (self *Obj1) Id() string {
    return "Obj1id"
}

func (self *Obj1) Name() string {
    return "Obj1"
}

func (self *Obj1) Run() string {
    return "Obj1 run func"
}

type Function func() string

type Struct struct {
    name        string
    runFunc    Function
    isCompleted bool
}

func New(impl IStruct) *Struct {
    return &Struct{
        name:        impl.Name(),
        runFunc:     impl.Run,
        isCompleted: false,
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Obj1
0x6f6e00
```

When i call the names of structs that implements IStruct it works but when i call runFunc from structs it returns hex adress what should i do to run when i call runFuncs.

The last thing I wonder here is when I want to use a structure that implements a certain interface as an interface, I give the address of the structure, why does this happen?

Comment: You may want to fix your code and the question to match. There is no `scanFunc` so your code does not even run. And the `iAnalyzer` mentioned in your question is not there.

Comment: I fixed the mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `runFunc` is a function. Printing a function is just printing its address.

If you want to print its output, you need to actually execute it:

```
fmt.Println(structObj.runFunc())
```

On the other hand, `name` is a string, so printing it works exactly as expected.

As for your second question, you need to call `New(&Obj1)` because all the methods implementing the interface are using pointer receivers: `(self *Obj1)`.

This means that `*Obj1` implements the interface, but `Obj1` does not. If you want it to, you can change all your receivers to value receivers: `(self Obj1)` and you will be able to call `New(Obj1)`

Comment: Do you know the answer of second question?